# Ассемблер. Стоит ли его изучать теперь?

Tags: fasm, ассемблер, masm32

Я студент 2-го курса. Программирование мы начинали изучать сразу же с языка C, сейчас заканчивается курс ООП С++ (я не говорю про вспомогательные предметы типа основ конструирования программ и так далее). Мне нравится программировать, но меня никогда не покидала мысль: может стоит сначала разобраться в Ассемблере? Хочу конечно же когда-нибудь стать профессионалом и, разумеется, работать по специальности. Но хочется спросить: **уместно ли изучение Ассемблера?** Просто я ожидаю, что, изучив его, я больше буду понимать "внутреннюю реализацию". Но тут опять же вопрос: **так ли важно это понимание, что внутри происходит?** Я не знаю, понадобиться ли мне он на будущей работе, так как я, вероятнее всего, буду работать с языками высокого уровня. Может быть я смогу писать более оптимизированные программы. **Но смогу ли так много выиграть за счет этого?** Да и вообще сейчас особо с ресурсами проблем нет. А если еще подумать про читаемость кода... Думаю, она резко уменьшится, если я буду пользоваться Ассемблерными вставками (хотя я не уверен, что они используются для опитимизации :D). **А может она мне в отладке поможет?** Печально, что пока в универе на это внимание почти не уделяется, но я думаю, что это важно, особенно на следующих этапах, когда программы станут серьезными.

Естественно, польза хоть какая-то будет, если я его изучу и разберусь с "внутренней реализацией". **Но "окупятся" ли усилия на изучения Ассемблера? Или может быть мне лучше начать изучать что-то более "дельное"?**

*Заранее спасибо ;)*

Comment: Скромное ИМХО - и без ассемблера есть что учить (т.е. - понимать неплохо, но, мягко говоря, не обязательно).

Вообще я бы не учил т.к. не считаю, что это себя окупает.

Вот если вы, например, выберете системное программирование, тогда да - учить без вариантов

Comment: Системное программирование - не просто учить, а ковырять до посинения. Ну, а для пожизненного занятия PHP, может, и не стоит.

Comment: @AlexWindHope программист без понимания работы стеков-регистров-памяти-указателей-адресации - да, способен только быдлокодить на php =) Ассемблер позволяет это выучить *из необходимости* - с ним по-другому нельзя)) Поэтому и советуют его учить/практиковать, смысл совсем не в командах (их можно прочитать и повторить вслух с первого раза), он дает именно навык прямой работы с памятью. Причем сравнительно просто и быстро эти навыки приходят (добиться ошибки адресации в php/js/as невозможно в принципе)

Comment: Пасаны так мб го на машинном коде писать? -_-

Comment: У меня в школе была такая мечта)) Кстати, если овладеть альт-вводом символов, ассемблером и hex'ом, можно в блокноте экзешники писать)

Comment: C крестами все замечательно, собственно не вижу смысла опускаться еще ниже, вот хоть убей - не вижу. Нормального обоснования так и не увидел. (коммент, естественно, читал)

Как-раз таки не лень, просто не вижу смысла, надеялся увидеть текст, который изменил-бы мое отношение к этому вопросу - но нет, очередные ответы из разряда - "так нада".

PS: сложилось впечатление что я слоупок, но раз так - распишите, если кому не лень, на пальцах, что-бы даже такой слоупок понял и увидел несомненную пользу, ту великую истину, без которой "мне не стать больше чем PHP быдлокодером".

Comment: @AlexWindHope, я про PHP-быдлокодеров ничего не писал. Думаю, если заниматься ИСКЛЮЧЕТИЛЬНО Web-программированием, то можно ассемблер опустить и стать прекрасным программистом. Если же серьезно заняться десктоповым программированием (плохо сказано, но Вы меня поняли), то тут ОЗНАКОМИТЬСЯ совсем не помешает, если есть желание уйти дальше рисования формочек в дельфях. Собственно, остальное я написал в ответе. Потом, если Вы считаете, что Вам лично это не нужно, то я не собираюсь Вас переубеждать. Учите или не учите, что хотите.

Comment: Блин, ассемблер - это прямая работа с памятью. По аналогии с обработкой дерева, PHP - огромная циркулярка, C# - лазерный резак, ASM - нож. И познавать надо не нож, а прямую обработку дерева, почувствовать его в руках, увидеть вблизи всякие занозы, сучки, от коры почистить, пальцы порезать в конце концов)) Никто не говорит, что надо всю жизнь работать ножом, но не уметь, кстати, и в этой сфере позорно. К слову, ножом можно вырезать все, от матрешки до статуи, а на циркулярке... тоже, только матрешка будет полтонны весом. Аналогия понятна?)

Comment: @Sh4dow - во, то что нужно, спс, аналогия кстати интересная.

Comment: @mikillskegg Какой ассемблер для какой платформы рекомендуете "ковырять до посинения" для системного программирования? (Вспоминаем linux и платформы, на которых оно работает) @Sh4dow Прекрасная аналогия. Надо построить дом, и плотник аккуратненько обстругивает брёвна (и пазы в них делает) кухонным ножом. (А это очень непросто)

Comment: @alexlz, для той платформы, с которой человек планирует работать.

Comment: @mikillskegg Пропагандируете самоограничение?. "У вас есть цветные телевизоры? -- Да -- Ну дайте мне зелёный". Для реальных приложений ниша применения ассемблера весьма невелика. (Даже микроконтроллеры 2Kб флеш + 128б RAM -- уже спорно, а про выше -- ну его нафиг).

Comment: Я вообще-то писал про разработчиков ОС, а не прикладного софта.

Comment: Разработчику ОС надо знать возможности аппаратуры (платформы). Да и то в несколько ином разрезе. Что касается машинных команд, то их должен знать тот, кто пишет кодогенератор к транслятору и/или низкоуровневую оптимизацию кодов.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Коварная постановка вопроса, холиварная такая :)

Скажу так: знать его очень желательно, причем желательность прямо пропорциональна высокоуровневости основного языка. Если это C - можно не учить, если это js/php/c# - обязательно. Не нужно даже делать ассемблерные вставки и кодить юниты на нем, но желательно именно знать, что там происходит внутри. Просто чтобы не возникало глупых вопросов вида "почему после **`int i = 0; if (i++ > 0) { code }`** i не становится обратно нулем?". Также он очень хорошо лечит от индусского кода.

А насчет окупится-нет... Ну, это долгосрочное вложение, оно может окупиться незаметно, а может и очень пригодиться, если будете разрабатывать высоконагруженные приложения. В любом случае если не сейчас, то в качестве хобби было бы неплохо хоть пару утилиток на нем накидать в свободное время, гарантирую веселое времяпровождение)

Comment: тоже как-нибудь попробую покопаться...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
На руках имеется учебник В.И. Юрова "Assembler" 2-ое издание. Подойдет ли он мне? =)

Comment: @xopkpykc если честно, не в курсе, я им сам занимаюсь именно как хобби, использую только примеры из инета.

Comment: Отличный ответ. Сам (пока читал вопрос) думал написать в том же духе.

Хочу еще добавить, что на 2-м курсе Вы **абсолютно** не можете достоверно прогнозировать характер Вашей деятельности через, скажем, 5 лет после окончания ВУЗа.

Answer (score 13):

Может, глубоко копать ассемблер не стоит (если, конечно, не собираетесь заниматься разработкой ОС, драйверов, встроенных систем и пр.), но ознакомиться стоит обязательно. И знать, что происходит внутри, как устроен процесс, как происходит вызов функций и т.д., любой профессиональный программист должен обязательно. Это не теоретические рассуждения, это из опыта. Мне изучение ассемблера крайне помогло, даже в изучении достаточно высокоуровневых вещей.

А ознакомится на требуемом уровне можно за месяц-полтора. Сразу изучайте плоскую модель. Всяких досовских заморочек даже не касайтесь, это совершенно ни к чему.

Answer (score 8):

Изучая ассемблер вы изучаете архитектуру системы, в самом языке изучать нечего - он крайне прост. По поводу пользы вряд ли тут можно что-то сказать заранее, смотря каким программистом вы хотите стать: если прикладным, то скорее всего нет, а вот если системным, то это вам определенно очень поможет. К примеру в какой-нибудь антивирусной конторе без него никак, в то время как разрабатывая программы для бухгалтеров вы без него прекрасно обойдетесь. В любом случае знания лишними не бывают, и если вам это интересно, то изучите его хотя бы факультативно. Только я настоятельно советую разобраться сначала с высокоуровневым языком - так будет правильнее с моей точки зрения, т.к. в обратной последовательности идет очень туго.

Answer (score 5):

Имея в багаже С/C++, поковырять ассемблер, хотя бы чтобы изучить его возможности и архитектуру, будет очень полезно, на мой взгляд. Если Вам он когда-то действительно понадобиться - Вы будете знать, где искать и что учить. И действительно понимания в С/C++ он добавит.

Лишних знаний вообще нет.

Answer (score 4):

Скажу, что элементарные ассемблеровские операторы надо знать по-любому, а еще лучше владеть им хотя бы на уровне "багокопателя". Ведь многие современные компиляторы компилируют написанный вами код в asm-код. Иногда надо знать, как именно компилятор транслировал ваш код, например, на C++ в машинный, чтобы, к примеру отыскать корень ошибки. А вообще, все пентестеры, все крякеры используют такой инструмент, как дизассемблер. Чтобы искать баги в чьем-либо программном коде и писать эксплоиты, к примеру.

Comment: "Ведь многие современные компиляторы компилируют написанный вами код в asm-код" Сильный аргумент. И был вполне обоснован лет 30 назад (когда качество компиляторов было существенно ниже). И, кстати, что значит "элементарные ассемблеровские операторы"? Они разные для разных ассемблеров, а если машинные команды -- для разных архитектур.

Comment: Думаю, здесь идет речь о ассемблере для Windows, а не для самодельных контроллеров =)

Comment: 1. Windows NT была для трёх архитектур (x86, alpha, MIPS). Сейчас вроде тоже собираются количество архитектур увеличивать. 2. А что такое "ассемблер для самодельных контроллеров"?

Comment: Вот тут пошло более конкретное обсуждение. 

Ограничиваться изучением x-86 **нельзя** (просто это дурацкая, хотя и самая распространенная  система команд). Затем, надо различать Ассемблер, как синтаксис описания команд/данных/указаний линкеру от описания системы команд/архитектуры.

На какие архитектуры смотреть ? X-86, SPARC, ARM. Для понимания истории (и как следствие будущего) архитектур - IBM-360, PDP/11, MC68K.

Независимо от системы команд надо хорошо разобраться в механизме виртуальной памяти и кэширования в CPU и ознакомиться с SIMD (векторные команды).

Comment: И уж тем более нельзя ограничиваться изучением x51. Хотя она-то как раз под ассемблер заточена.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не стоит.

Изучение  ассемблера по книжкам десятилетней давности даст вам [ложное представление](http://habrahabr.ru/post/43905/) о работе процессора, расширит кругозор и поднимет ЧСВ. Еще при наличии времени стоит изучить схемотехнику, чтобы знать, как из логических элементов создаются регистры. И прикладную теорию цифровых автоматов, чтобы знать, как сделана операция деления и почему она занимает больше времени.

Но в целом это просто just for fun, в жизни редко встречается.

Comment: "Огромное спасибо за интересную статью!". Кстати, копипаст оттуда и я пишу это искренне.

Все верно, а если глянуть на ccNUMA и возможности InfiniBand по прямому доступу к памяти другого узла **и возможную маскировку софтом** этого, а также обратить внимание на модную сейчас виртуализацию железа то еще на 2 порядка вернее.

Но, без понимания основ (книжки десятилетней (двадцати (это от себя)) давности) проблем с эффективностью в современном IT мире **не понять**. Без этих книг такие статьи будут пустым звуком. Т.е. вопрос отнюдь не just for fun.

Comment: плюс за оппозицию и смелость взглядов :)

Answer (score 0):

Все эти ответы хороши, но проблема в том что Ассемблер человеку все равно придется изучить, только будет это на курсе 4 (ну мне так помнится)... а еще помнится экзамен по сему предмету, на котором мы писали код на листочках в клеточку (эх были же времена :) )

но суть не в этом , так или иначе вы его все равно будете изучать, но лучше быть во всеоружии изначально ;)

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум ознакомиться стоит, хотя бы ради для расширения кругозора.

Answer (score 0):

Я не буду ортодоксом - поддержку оппозиционную точку зрения и плюсану [[@beardog](/users/1319/beardog)](/users/1319/beardog). Согласен, что знание ассемблера не есть необходимость и может быть местами даже и вредно.

Понятно, что сишнику без ассемблера никуда, но джависту/джаверу - зачем, зачем SQL прогеру? Чисто just for fun - абсолютно согласен.

**P.S.** Я ассемблер увы знаю и иногда думаю, что это только вредит мне...

Comment: @Barmaley, а архитектуру компьютера изучать стоит? 

Если да, то на определенном этапе поучить какой-нибудь ассемблер наверное придется. В конце-то концов "программировать всухую", используя абстактную систему команд IMHO просто не очень интересно.

Хотя... Я где-то читал, что Керниган не знал ни одного. Может это правда, а может и нет.

Comment: @avp Лет 10 назад я бы согласился, что стоит знать архитектуру компьютера, но сейчас - я уже сомневаюсь когда вижу что 10-летние пацаны запросто пишут довольно сложные аппы для iOS или на VB

Comment: @Barmaley, говоря изучать архитектуру, я в качестве цели изучения имел в виду не близкий к аппаратуре хакинг, а проектирование больших систем. 

Согласитесь, что люди, толком не понимающие, что на самом деле происходит внутри "рядов этих шкафов, уходящих вдаль" (и как устроена ОС, и как работает сеть и т.п.) частенько здорово ошибаются в оценке объемов данных, которые хотят обработать.

Comment: @Barmaley соскучились по весне (вопрос-то мартовский)? И что означает фраза

     Понятно, что сишнику без ассемблера никуда

Answer (score -1):

Асм был, есть и будет всегда! Поэтому изучать его надо в любом случае!

Comment: Да нет, не всегда он был. На первых (да и не только на первых, на вторых и третьих тоже) компутерах программы писали в машинных кодах.

Comment: А ты уверен, что "всегда" относится и к "был"? Мне так кажется, что оно относится к "будет". Хотя, это тоже вопрос спорный, неизвестно, что в будущем будет изобретено, но для обозримого будущего это суждение верно.